# How to make a simple Bayesian neural network for multiclass classification in pymc2

Tags: python, mcmc, bayesian-networks, iris-dataset

I want to build a BNN model for iris dataset in pymc2.

I defined my model and I tried to train but the accuracy is just `0.33` on train and test data.

This is my current code

```
iterations = 2000
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :]
Y = iris.target

X = scale(X)
X = X.astype(float)
Y = Y.astype(float)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.5)

w11 = pm.Normal('w11', mu=0., tau=1.)
w12 = pm.Normal('w12', mu=0., tau=1.)
w21 = pm.Normal('w21', mu=0., tau=1.)
w22 = pm.Normal('w22', mu=0., tau=1.)
w31 = pm.Normal('w31', mu=0., tau=1.)
w32 = pm.Normal('w32', mu=0., tau=1.)

x1 = X_train[:, 0]
x2 = X_train[:, 1]
# x3 = X_train[:, 2]
# x4 = X_train[:, 3]

x3 = pm.Lambda('x3', lambda w1=w11, w2=w12: np.tanh(w1 * x1 + w2 * x2))
x4 = pm.Lambda('x4', lambda w1=w21, w2=w22: np.tanh(w1 * x1 + w2 * x2))


@pm.deterministic
def activation(x=w31 * x3 + w32 * x4):
    return 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x)) #sigmoid


y = pm.Categorical('y', activation, observed=True, value=Y_train)

model = pm.Model([w11, w12, w21, w22, w31, w32, y])
inference = pm.MCMC(model)
inference.sample(iterations)

y_pred_train = pm.Categorical('y_pred_train', activation)
print("Accuracy on train data = {}".format((y_pred_train.value == Y_test).mean()))

x1 = X_test[:, 0]
x2 = X_test[:, 1]

inference.sample(iterations)

y_pred_test = pm.Categorical('y_pred_test', activation)
print("Accuracy on test data = {}".format((y_pred_test.value == Y_test).mean()))
```

My network architecture is

[image: my_network_architecture]

I am not sure if the problem is in Categorical distribution for `y`, `y_pred_train` and `y_pred_test`. And I can't trace this variables with `inference.trace("y")[:]` to view what exactly is inside.

My current results

```
Accuracy on train data = 0.3333333333333333
Accuracy on test data = 0.3333333333333333
```

Do you have any suggestions to improve this score?